# Bicep to act as a template for deploying app service and related resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I have individual biceps for app insight, app service plan, and, app service.

I am creating a template bicep where I will call each of these as modules to deploy one app service.
And now whenever for any of my solutions I need to deploy an app service, I will just call this template with minimum parameters so it can deploy an app service with all required supporting resources like app service plan and app insight.

The situation I am stuck with now is I need one app service plan to host two app services one for web and the other for api and each of them should have their own app insight.

The individual modules are very simple, I am still giving a sample for app service plan below:

```
//asp.bicep
param planName string
param planLocation string = resourceGroup().Location
param planSku string
param planTier string

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = { name: planName, location: planLocation, sku: { 
name: planSku
tier: planTier
]}

output appPlanId string = appServicePlan.id
```

Below I have the app service template where all the individual biceps are being called as modules, shown below:

```
//astemplate.bicep
param rgLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param name string
param planSku string
param planTier string
param appSettings array = []
param netFrameworkVersion string

var appInsightModule = '${name}-AIModule'
var appServicePlanModule = '${name}-ASPModule'
var appServiceModule = '${name}-ASModule'

module aspModule ''={
 name: appServicePlanModule
 params: {
  planName: name
  planLocation: rgLocation
  planSku: planSku
  planTier: planTier
 }
}

module aiAppModule '' = {
 name: '${appInsightModule}-forApp'
 params: {
  name: '${name}-ai-app'
  location: rgLocation
 } 
}

module aiApiModule '' = {
 name: '${appInsightModule}-forApi'
 params: {
  name: '${name}-ai-api'
  location: rgLocation
 } 
}

module asAppModule '' = {
 name: '${appServiceModule}-app'
 params: {
  name: '${name}-app'
  rgLocation: rgLocation
  appInsightsKey: aiAppModule.outputs.instrumentationkey
  appServicePlanId: aspModule.outputs.appPlanId
  appSettings: appSettings
  netFrameworkVersion: netFrameworkVersion 
 }
 dependsOn: [aspModule, aiAppModule] 
}

module asApiModule '' = {
 name: '${appServiceModule}-api'
 params: {
  name: '${name}-api'
  rgLocation: rgLocation
  appInsightsKey: aiApiModule.outputs.instrumentationkey
  appServicePlanId: aspModule.outputs.appPlanId
  appSettings: appSettings
  netFrameworkVersion: netFrameworkVersion 
 }
 dependsOn: [aspModule, aiApiModule] 
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a way to have to make just one call to app insight module and one to app service module instead of two calls each? Because I want this template to satisfy all permutation and combination. If I decide to have one app insight for all app services or one for each.

For App Insight, I was thinking of passing names app insight resources in an array and use for loop at the individual bicep level(resource) but then I got stuck with assigning the appropriate app insight to its related app service.

I hope the question is clear, please let me know if more details or other individual bicep is also required?

Comment: Can you share all the modules bicep code and brief me about what exactly you are trying? @Lucky

Comment: @Jahnavi Apologies for delay, I got a way (may not be most intelligent) which I will post below. However, I will add the remaining bicep here as well and what I was trying to do is have a bicep template which can be called by any one to deploy an app service and its related resources namely insight and hosting plan. The twist was I wanted it to be flexible enough to address all permutation and combination.

Comment: For e.g. I can have one asp hosting multiple app services and each having their own app insight, or one asp hosting multiple app services and all referring to one app insight, or one asp each for each app service with their own app insights.

Comment: Hope the answer makes it clear

Comment: I think you should evaluate a [Bicep Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/private-module-registry?tabs=azure-powershell) for hosting your shared modules.

Comment: Thank you DreadedFrost. I do have my bicep modules being published in azure container registry. I just did not want to add that complication in my question. I have the individual bicep for resources and templates for things like app services which needs some supporting resources like hosting plan/app insights. So I can call template once rather than calling three different individual templates from my application.

Comment: But I also wanted a flexibility in case someone wants app services having their own unique plan/insights or shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//AppInsight bicep
param name string

param location string = resourceGroup().location

param aiPostFix string = 'ai'

var aiName = '${name}-${aiPostFix}'

resource appInsight 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: aiName
  kind: 'web'
  location: location
  properties:{
    Application_Type:'web'
    Request_Source:'rest'
    Flow_Type:'Bluefield'
  }
}

output instrumentationKey string = appInsight.properties.InstrumentationKey
output insightsName string = appInsight.properties.Name

//ASP bicep
param planName string
param planLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param planSku string
param planTier string

param aspPostFix string = 'asp'

var aspName = '${planName}-${aspPostFix}'

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = { name: aspName, location: planLocation, sku: {
    name: planSku
    tier: planTier
  } }

  output appPlanId string = appServicePlan.id

//App service bicep
param rgLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param name string
param appServicePlanId string
param appServicePostFix string = 'as'
param netFrameworkVersion string = 'v6.0'
param appInsightsKey string
param appSettings array = []

var appServiceName = '${name}-${appServicePostFix}'

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: appServiceName
  location: rgLocation
  properties:{
    serverFarmId: appServicePlanId
    siteConfig:{
      alwaysOn: true
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      netFrameworkVersion: netFrameworkVersion
      appSettings: appSettings
    }
    httpsOnly: true    
  }
}

output appServiceId string = appService.id
```

Now the app service template bicep

```
//astemplate bicep

param rgLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param aspName string
param planSku string = 'XXX'
param planTier string = 'XXX'
param appSettings array = XXX
param netFrameworkVersion string = 'XXX'
param aiName string
param asName string

var aiModule = '${aiName}-AIModule'
var hostingModule = '${aspName}-ASPModule'
var asModule = '${asName}-ASModule'

module aspModule 'asplan.bicep' = {
  name: hostingModule
  params: {
    planName: aspName
    planLocation: rgLocation
    planSku: planSku
    planTier: planTier
  }
}

module appInsightModule 'ai.bicep' = {
  name: aiModule
  params: {
    name: aiName
    location: rgLocation
  }
}

module appServiceAppModule 'as.bicep' = {
  name: asModule
  params: {
    name: asName
    rgLocation: rgLocation
    appInsightsKey: appInsightModule.outputs.instrumentationKey
    appServicePlanId: aspModule.outputs.appPlanId
    appSettings: appSettings
    netFrameworkVersion: netFrameworkVersion
  }
  dependsOn: [ aspModule, appInsightModule ]
}
```

Now for e.g. I need one asp which hosts two app services and both have their own app insight

```
module appServiceApiTemplateModule 'astemplate.bicep' = {
  name: '${prefixRName}-ApiModule'
  params: {    
    aspName: prefixRName
    aiName: '${prefixRName}-web1'
    asName: '${prefixRName}-web1'
    appSettings: [      
      {
        name: 'Environment'
        value: environment
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can call the above module again and update aiName and asName parameter web1 to web2 and it will deploy one more app service with its own app insight but on the same hosting plan.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).